# Could EntityState.Modified cause Insert operation to be performed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-6

I am reading the following tutorial about entity framework 6 [Link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). And inside the section named ”Adding an Edit Page for Instructors”, the author wrote the following code inside the Post edit action method:-

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult EditPost(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    var instructorToUpdate = db.Instructors
       .Include(i => i.OfficeAssignment)
       .Where(i => i.ID == id)
       .Single();

    if (TryUpdateModel(instructorToUpdate, "",
       new string[] { "LastName", "FirstMidName", "HireDate", "OfficeAssignment" }))
    {
       try
       {
          if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(instructorToUpdate.OfficeAssignment.Location))
          {
             instructorToUpdate.OfficeAssignment = null;
          }

          db.Entry(instructorToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
          db.SaveChanges();

          return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }
       catch (RetryLimitExceededException /* dex */)
      {
         //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
         ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
      }
   }
   return View(instructorToUpdate);
}
```

This code will cover these three conditions:-

- If the user clears the office assignment and it originally had a value, you must remove and delete the OfficeAssignment entity.
- If the user enters an office assignment value and it originally was empty, you must create a new OfficeAssignment entity.
- If the user changes the value of an office assignment, you must change the value in an existing OfficeAssignment entity.

So does this means that

```
db.Entry(instructorToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

will cause an insert statement to be performed for the OfficeAssignment record incase the Instructor did not have a prevouse OfficeAssignment object ? and what is the rule that govern this ?

here is the complete model diagram:-
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DbContext.Entry` method is used to do an **explicit loading**, that means that It gives you access to all the information that the DbContext has about an entity. This goes beyond the values that are stored in the properties of the actual entity and includes things such as the **state of the entity** and the original values for each property when it was retrieved from the database.

When you call the [`TryUpdateModel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470908(v=vs.108).aspx) method, it will update the properties (that you pass their names as a parameter) with values from the model binder. One of these properties is `OfficeAssignment`, wich is updated too. If in your view you don't enter a `Location`, then you don't have reason to create a new `OfficeAssigment` (that's way you need to do `instructorToUpdate.OfficeAssignment = null;` because even when you don't enter a new `Location`, you will have a instance of `OfficeAssignment`). If you add a new `Location`, you are going to create a new `OfficeAssignment`, and if you modified the `Location`, then you are going to modified its value. 
When you do this:

```
db.Entry(instructorToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

You are going to set a flag on the entity indicating it has been changed. When the `SaveChanges` method is called, the `Modified` flag causes the Entity Framework to create SQL statements to update the database row. All columns of the database row will be updated, including those that the user didn't change, and concurrency conflicts are ignored. To understand better what happend, you can look the `Instructor` instance like a tree. Code First recognizes that you have a navegation property, so it need to be updated or insterted(depending on the case). If the `OfficeAssignment` have an `Id` different of the `default(int)` (I'm pressuming that is an interger), then it will be updated, and in other case, it will be inserted.

Comment: thanks for the reply,, but it is not related to my question,, i do understand the code (no need to explain it). my question is basically when will EntityState.Modified cause an insert statement to be executed and when it will cuase an update statment to be executed ? because in the example if the user add a new location (and the instructor did not already have an OfficeAssigment assigned to it) this will cause an insert statement to be executed to add a new Officeassigment , while if the instructor already have

Comment: Officeassinment then EntityState.Modified will cause an update statement on the OfficeAssinmetn instead of executing an insert stamtnet? so my question is what govern this behavior !!

Comment: Hello @johnG, I updated the last paragraph explaining what is behavior which causes the insert operation

Comment: thanks a lot for the last paragraph, so EntityState.Modified will execute an insert statement if the navigation property PK  = default(int) ? is this correct? On the same side can the EntityState.Modified cause an insert statement for the Instructor object , or this only applies on the navigation property ?

Comment: About the first part, that is correct. Now, Modified state is used to update an entity that is already in DB, so, it will not cause an insert statement for an Instructor object.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two ways an entity can be persisted through EF.

**A.** Add it directly to the Dbset with the additional relationships you want it to have.

```
Entity e = new Entity();
e.ForeignEntityId = 123;
context.Entities.Add(e);
context.SaveChanges();
```

**B.** Attach it to an existing entity and if that entity is/was untracked, mark that entity as `Modified.

```
Entity e = new Entity();
ForeignEntity fe = context.Find(...);
//Only needed if 'fe' was untracked
//context.Entry(fe).State = EntityState.Modified; 
fe.Entity = e;
context.SaveChanges();
```

The way presented in your question is the second way. It's all about getting the "new" object to be present in the object graph that represents all tracked EF entities from your DB.

Comment: but your second approach is different from the approach i am asking about. now i though that using EntityState.Modified will always cause an update statement to be performed on the database. but seems that EntityState.Modified will cause an insert statement to be initiate in-case the OfficeAssigment does not exists in the database or it does not have a PK assigned to it ? so what is the rules the govern this ? will for example EntityState.Modified cause an insert statement to be executed for any entity that does not have a PK ?

Comment: also your two approaches A & B are different. inside approach A the e entity will be saved to the DB, while in the approach B ,nothing will happen since you did not use Entitystate.Modified ? is this correct?

Comment: @johnG You don't need to set the entitstate to `Modified` unless that entity had changed when it wasn't being tracked by EF. In the case of your example that line is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,can load the DbContext.Entry method and can be  used to do an explicit loading as mentioned above

I will suggest rather do Delete and Insert until you do not have real-time needs of modification.

```
{
  //Remove existing data           
  modelname existingobj = dbobj.tablename.Find(id);        
  dbobj.tablename.Remove(existingobj);
  dbobj.SaveChanges();

  //Add data
  dbobj.Entry(existingobj).State = EntityState.Added;         
  dbobj.SaveChanges();
}
```